# How to get ASP.NET MVC Action Method to Parse a Property defined in an Interface and implemented in an Abstract class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a wizard with 5 steps, each step has a View Model that implements `IUserAddUpdateStep` `Interface`.

An Action Method in my Controller looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddUpdate(IUserAddUpdateStep step)
```

And a `DefaultModelBinder` override to let ASP.NET know how to deal with `IUserAddUpdateStep`and get the concrete type for deserialization for HTTP posts to the above controller action method, `AddUpdate`:

```
 public class StepViewModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
    {
        protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
        {
            ValueProviderResult stepTypeValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("StepType");
            Type stepType = Type.GetType((string)stepTypeValue.ConvertTo(typeof(string)), true);
            object step = Activator.CreateInstance(stepType);
            bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => step, stepType);
            return step;
        }
    }
```

I post View Models of type "IUserAddStep", like so in my `AddUpdate.cshtml` view:

```
@model UserAddUpdate

@{
    IUserAddUpdateStepcurrentStep = Model.Steps[Model.CurrentStepIndex];
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddUpdate", "Employee", FormMethod.Post, new { @role = "form" }))
{
     @Html.Hidden("StepType", currentStep.GetType())
     @Html.EditorFor(x => currentStep, null, "")

     <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

You do not need to worry about `Model` `UserAddUpdate` so much for this question, it just contains a list of `IUserAddUpdateStep` but here is what it looks like

```
 public class UserAddUpdate
    {
        public int CurrentStepIndex { get; set; }
        public IList<IUserAddUpdateStep> Steps { get; set; }

        public void Initialize()
        {
            Steps = typeof(IUserAddUpdateStep)
                .Assembly
                .GetTypes()
                .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract && typeof(IUserAddUpdateStep).IsAssignableFrom(t))
                .Select(t => (IUserAddUpdateStep)Activator.CreateInstance(t))
                .ToList();

        }
    }
```

`@Html.EditorFor`, for a particular step, will load a .cshtml Editor Template matching a concrete implementation View Model of type `IUserAddUpdateStep`.

This setup all works great!

Then I wanted a common value to be shared between all View Models that implement `IUserAddUpdateStep` I added the common property to `IUserAddUpdateStep`:

```
public interface IUserAddUpdateStep
{
    string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

And then my View Models inherit from a new base abstract class instead of `IUserAddUpdateStep` :

```
public abstract class UserAddUpdateStepBase: IUserAddUpdateStep
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

And then specific concrete implementation View Models of type look like this:

```
public class UserAddUpdateOverview: UserAddUpdateStepBase 
{
}
```

UserAddUpdateOverview is still of type `IUserAddUpdateStep` but now inherits from the abstract base class `UserAddUpdateStepBase`.

And finally I added to my AddUpdate.cshtml view, with in my form of course:

```
 <input type="hidden" id="UserId" value="@(((UserAddUpdateStepBase) currentStep).UserId)"/>
```

**Everything still works great except for the `UserId` property, I cannot get that to deserialize when the form posts to my controller method `public ActionResult AddUpdate(IUserAddUpdateStep step)`. `UserId` is null.**

I can see the hidden input value using browser F12 Developer Tools Inspector in the DOM, it is a child of my `<form />`:

[image]

I have also tried:

```
<input type="hidden" id="UserAddUpdateStepBase_UserId" value="@(((UserAddUpdateStepBase) currentStep).UserId)"/>
```

And:

```
<input type="hidden" id="UserAddUpdateStepBase.UserId" value="@(((UserAddUpdateStepBase) currentStep).UserId)"/>
```

And:

```
 <input type="hidden" id="IUserAddUpdateStep.UserId" value="@(((UserAddUpdateStepBase) currentStep).UserId)"/>
```

And:

```
 <input type="hidden" id="IUserAddUpdateStep_UserId" value="@(((UserAddUpdateStepBase) currentStep).UserId)"/>
```

My solution, for now, will be to remove the abstract base class and just implement the `UserId` property in each concrete implementation View Model of type `IUserAddUpdateStep`. But if anyone has an explanation on how I might guide ASP.NET to correctly deserialize my hidden input UserId that maps to my abstract class that would be awesome to know if their is a solution.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you should add `name` attribute rather than `id` on `input` tag to propertly send the value in the post.

Comment: @ArturoMenchaca oh wow, you are right about that! Testing

Comment: @ArturoMenchaca that was it!!!

Comment: @ArturoMenchaca go ahead and post your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `name` attribute on `input` tags to send the value in the post. In your case:

```
<input type="hidden" name="UserId" id="UserId" value="@(((UserAddUpdateStepBase) currentStep).UserId)"/>
```